# range function not passing all tests

Tags: sml

I am writing a range function that is supposed to return a list of integers in a specified range.

range(2,12,3) should return the list [2,5,8,11]

range(10,2,~1) should return the list [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3]

for range(2,12,3) this works:

```
fun range(start, stop, step) =
if start > stop then nil
else start::range(start+step, stop, step);
```

for range(10,2,~1) this works:

```
fun range(start,stop,step) =
if start <= stop then nil
else start::range(start+step, stop, step);
```

However, I need one function to handle both cases. I have tried using orelse and else if as follows but the function returns an empty list.

**orelse:**

```
fun range(start, stop, step) =
if start > stop orelse start <= stop then nil
else start::range(start+step, stop, step);
```

**else if:**

```
fun range(start,stop,step) =
if start > stop then nil
else if start <= stop then nil
else start::range(start+step,stop,step);
```

Both methods return

```
val it = [] : int list
```

I think it has something to do with using nil in the base case but I don't know why.

What needs to be changed so that the function returns the expected output for both tests?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing `stop` to `start`, consider the sign of `stop - start` and the sign of `step`.
If you think about that for a while, you will see that the signs are the same as long as you are inside the range.

```
fun sgn x = if x < 0 
            then ~1 
            else if x > 0 
                 then 1 
                 else 0;

fun range (start, stop, step) = if sgn(stop-start) = sgn(step)
                                then start :: range (start + step, stop, step)
                                else []
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

In both of your solutions the condition will be always `true`, because you're checking if `start` is either less than, greater than, or equal to `stop`, and this is matematically true for any pair of numbers.

**Solution:**

You must check the current situation according to the sign of `step`.

If `step` is zero, do not check anything else, as creating a range of step 0 is not possible. Throwing an exception would be a good option.

If `step` is positive, check that `start` is lower than `stop`. If not, stop.

If `step` is negative, check that `start` is higher than `stop`. If not, stop.

**Full code:**

```ml
fun range(start,stop,step) =
if start = stop orelse
(start < stop andalso step < 0) orelse
(start > stop andalso step > 0) then nil
else start::range(start+step, stop, step);
```